# Vue-Persist not reloading state after refresh

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have installed vue-persist from https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persist

I have set up the store and all is persisting to localStorage but on Pageload its not firing back into the store

```
import VuexPersist from "vuex-persist";

const vuexLocal = new VuexPersist({
    key: 'App',
    storage: window.localStorage
  });

export default{
    state: {
        pageTitle: "",
    },
    getters:{
        getPageTitle(state) {
            return state.pageTitle;
        },
    },
    actions: {},
    mutations:{
        pageTitle(state, payload) {
            this.state.pageTitle = payload
        },
    },
    plugins: [vuexLocal.plugin]
}
```

The app.js is pulling in the store here

```
import storeData from './store/index.js';

const store = new Vuex.Store(
   storeData,

);
```

Comment: Have you tried other storage methods than localStorage ? It can be disabled on your browser

Comment: I have also tried sessionStorage

Comment: Your syntax looks different than what's used in the package examples.  `VuexPersist` vs. `VuexPersistence`

Comment: It was an issue with some of the arrays in the code